# How to inject a service dependent on IOwinContext into custom OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, owin, autofac

Having an issue injecting IOwinContext into my OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider.

Inside my Startup.cs i have the line:

```
 public static IContainer ConfigureContainer(Type mvcApplication, HttpConfiguration configuration = null)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        //other stuff
        builder
          .Register(ctx=>HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext())
          .As<IOwinContext>();
        //other stuff
      app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
      app.UseAutofacWebApi(configuration);
      app.UseWebApi(configuration);
}
```

In my provider I do:

```
 public class  ApplicationOAuthProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider{

     public ApplicationOAuthProvider(IComponentContext context)
    {
        _ccontext = context;
    }

    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
           var logger = _ccontext.Resolve<EventLoggerService>();
    }

 }
```

The line above crashes because I have an injectable that needs `IOwinContext`.    The error is:

> : Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'Assistant.Framework.Services.CurrentUserService' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
>   Cannot resolve parameter 'Microsoft.Owin.IOwinContext context' of constructor 'Void .ctor(Microsoft.Owin.IOwinContext)'.

Comment: I think I made some progress here by setting the `InstancePerRequest()` but I'm still tracking down how I fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

#### Short version

You don't need to register `IOwinContext` in the container yourself if you use [Autofac and Web API integration using OWIN](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/webapi.html#owin-integration).

The integration package `Autofac.WebApi2.Owin` does it for you. All you have to do is inject `IOwinContext` wherever you want it to be injected and it will work out of the box, as you can see on [this repo on GitHub](https://github.com/mderriey/web-api-autofac-owin-context)

#### Longer version, a.k.a. *"how does this happen?"*

The reason is that when using the [OWIN integration package for Autofac](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Owin), the `IOwinContext` is automatically registered in every per-request lifetime scope. The magic happens when you call `app.UseAutofac(container)` in [this file](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Owin/blob/27a62994e5d794b5610354fd5fa613c36fa11961/src/Autofac.Integration.Owin/AutofacAppBuilderExtensions.cs#L325), and here's an excerpt of the code:

```cs
private static IAppBuilder RegisterAutofacLifetimeScopeInjector(this IAppBuilder app, ILifetimeScope container)
{
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            using (var lifetimeScope = container.BeginLifetimeScope(MatchingScopeLifetimeTags.RequestLifetimeScopeTag,
            b => b.RegisterInstance(context).As<IOwinContext>()))
            {
                context.Set(Constants.OwinLifetimeScopeKey, lifetimeScope);
                await next();
            }
        });

    app.Properties[InjectorRegisteredKey] = true;
    return app;
}
```

An anonymous middleware is registered in the OWIN pipeline, which does 3 things:

- Creates a new lifetime scope for the current HTTP request
- Registers the current `IOwinContext` in that new lifetime scope
- Stores the current lifetime scope in the `IOwinContext`

All this means that the lifetime scope that resolves your services in your Web API application already knows how to inject `IOwinService`, so no additional work is required on your side.

Comment: How does this help me?  I need access to the owincontext?

Comment: It was supposed to help you understand you don't need to register `IOwinContext` in the Autofac container. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: How can I get access to the context then?

Comment: You inject it in the constructor of whatever service you want it injected in. The only thing you have to change in your solution is you have to remove the `IOwinContext` registration in the container. I created a [repo on GitHub](https://github.com/mderriey/web-api-autofac-owin-context) if you want to have a look.

Comment: I dont really want to add a library to handle this I was trying to figure out why I couldn't inject it myself.  Thank you for the suggestion but I'm seeking to understand why mine wasn't working.

Comment: And as an FYI i tried this and it did not work.  I think it's because I'm trying to inject stuff into a custom OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider

Comment: try delegating the creation of the middleware to Autofac. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41183763/562839)

Comment: I've put together an example in this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/mderriey/autofac-owin-middleware)